# How to make a "wavy" path in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have an array of lines that each have a stroke:

[image]

Now I want each individual line to have a "wavy" effect like this:

[image]

How would go about something like this? - I've had no luck with the Warp > Wave effect.

Comment: I would probably try Wrap tool or Twirl tool with low intensity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways.

You could use an Envelope applied to the entire group as a mesh and move the mesh points to distort. (Object > Envelope > Make as Mesh...)

You could use the Warp tool in the Tool bar and manually "push" the paths into a shape you want.

You could apply an Envelope as an effect to each stroke, making each stroke wavy before the groups appearance.

You could recreate the starting line as a wave, then apply the effect to rotate the stroke.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out :)

I went with your last idea.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Zig Zag effect with smooth corners.

Answer (score 0):

Take your wavy line, and drag it into the brushes palette. That will give you a stroke swatch of a wavy line with a specific shape and number of bends. Apply that to your set of strokes pictured at the top.